# How to get each element from this complex array

Tags: jquery

I' am using innovative txt for sending sms and I'm receiving an array return like below.

```
{
    "message-count": 1,
    "messages": [
        {
            "status": 0,
            "to": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-ref": "",
            "message-id": "020000002177R34C",
            "message-price": "0.0100",
            "remaining-balance": "xxx.xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, how can I read each element using Jquery?

Please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: post some code, where you got stuck?

Comment: You don't need jQuery, you just need to know how to [access js object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try at below, where first string convert to json and access to object of json:

```
   var myjson = '{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}';
    var newJ= $.parseJSON(myjson);
        alert(newJ.TeamList[0].teamname);
```

==============================

```
var myjson ='{
    "message-count": 1,
    "messages": [
        {
            "status": 0,
            "to": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-ref": "",
            "message-id": "020000002177R34C",
            "message-price": "0.0100",
            "remaining-balance": "xxx.xxx"
        }
    ]
}';
 var newJ= $.parseJSON(myjson);
        alert(newJ.messages[0].status);
```

Comment: how can I read this in jQuery?
{
    "message-count":1,
    "error-text":"Invalid Phone format. Please ensusure phone number to be in international format. e.g 447876567655 ."
}

Comment: Please, use this blog for phone validation: "http://web-technos.blogspot.in/2011/09/advanced-jquery-form-validation-1-check.html"

Answer (score 1):

its a json string so use json_decode function to convert this into array then use loop or index to read the each every element

Comment: In case you missed it, the OP wants to do it using jQuery: `So, how can I read each element using Jquery?`.

Comment: OP wants to operate client side with all chance.

Comment: use this for jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 1):

```
    var obj='{
        "message-count": 1,
        "messages": [
            {
                "status": 0,
                "to": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "client-ref": "",
                "message-id": "020000002177R34C",
                "message-price": "0.0100",
                "remaining-balance": "xxx.xxx"
            }
        ]
    }'
    obj.message-count;
    obj.messages.status
```

read the json object using the method mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery, the following should work or at least give you a hint

```
$.get('/..url returning the data in your example../' , function (data) {
 $.each(data.messages, function (index, message) {
       // message.status will contain "0" in your example
  });
});
```

Refer http://jquery.com/ for the documentation

Answer (score -1):

on ajax success use something like that

```
json = $.parseJSON(yourresponse);

$.each(json.messages,function(ind,value){
    console.log(value.status);
});
```

Comment: why not or what else you do?

Comment: see i have not downvoted it, but you tell me what is the output of `console.log(json.value);`.

Comment: your status,to,client-ref,message_id,message-price and rem. blnc

Comment: okay then why should OP do it in the loop of `$.each()` you can get it  outside of loop too.

Comment: outside the loop you have to define index but it didn't mean that you can output outside the loop

Comment: Still you are not understanding it this wont give you which you think to output `console.log(json.value);` it should be `console.log(value);` only or if you want status out of it then `console.log(value.status);`

Comment: sorry for my mistake i didn't see this thanxs mate :-)